# How to convert from long long to DRAWITEMSTRUCT*

Tags: c++, winapi, type-conversion, 64-bit

I have this function:

```
GwBoolean win95_draw_button(DRAWITEMSTRUCT *pDrawParam, GwCore *pCore)
{
    ...
    assert(pDrawParam);
    HDC hDC = pDrawParam->hDC;
    ...
}
```

And I get this Exception:

Exception thrown: read access violation.
pDrawParam was 0x2B4FE760. The exception is pointing at `HDC hDC = pDrawParam->hDC;`

HDC is defined like this:

```
HANDLE HDC 
value: void*
```

and this hDC on the right site like this:

HDC hDC in struct tagDRAWITEMSTRUCT The function win95_draw_button is called here:

```
GwBoolean GwPushButton::EventHandler(GwEvent *ev)
{
     long long lParam;
     GwWord wParam;
     GwWindowParams(&wParam, &lParam);
     ...

     // Painting in Win95 Style
    win95_draw_button ((DRAWITEMSTRUCT*)(long long)(lParam),this);
}
```

GwWindowParams is defined like this (if it helps):

```
PREEXPORT void              POSTEXPORT GwWindowParams(GwWord* nwParam, long long* nlParam);
```

And the declaration looks like this:

```
 void GwWindowParams(GwWord *nwParam, long long *nlParam)
{
    GwFUNCTION_TRACE(GwWindowParams(GwWord *,long long*), 0)

    *nwParam = paramw;
    *nlParam = paraml;
}
```

paraml is defined like this: `static long paraml = 0L;`

I strongly assume that the problem here is lParam. lParam is of type long. I already tried and changed it to long long but I still got the exception. I guess this is also not the correct way `(DRAWITEMSTRUCT*)(long long)(lParam)` to convert to `DRAWITEMSTRUCT*`.

Comment: The correct way to convert a `long long` to a `DRAWITEMSTRUCT*` would be `reinterpret_cast<DRAWITEMSTRUCT*>(lParam)` as long as you know that the integer in lParam represents an address to a `DRAWITEMSTRUCT`. `(DRAWITEMSTRUCT*)lParam` also works but is not recommended as this is C-style.

Comment: I tried it with the reinterpret_cast but it did not work

Comment: The exception specifies that the given pointer is not a valid pointer (read access violation). So I assume that the integer stored in `lParam` does NOT represent an address to a `DRAWITEMSTRUCT`. As `paraml` is defined as `long` and not `long long`, the pointer information might be lost on 64-bit systems as a `long` might be defined as a 32-bit integer. The correct type to use for integers representing addresses would be `std::uintptr_t`. This is guaranteed to be large enough to contain an address.

Comment: Are you trying to write a message handler for [`WM_DRAWITEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-drawitem)? Are you sure you're processing that message when this code is running and not some other message? Each message uses its `wParam` and `lParam` values differently. (E.g., `WM_NCHITTEST` uses `lParam` for cursor coordinates, while `WM_SETTEXT` uses it point a pointer to a string.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your problem is the definition of `paraml`.

You are trying to store a 64-bit pointer in a 32-bit `long` which truncates the pointer, invalidating it.

Change `static long paraml = 0L;` to `static long long paraml = 0LL` or better `static std::uintptr_t paraml = 0;`.

`std::uintptr_t` is designed to be an integer type large enough to contain an address.

Casting `paraml` to `long long` is not sufficient as the information is already lost at that point.